# Is there a free VMWare Player for Mac?

Tags: vmware

There is a free player for vmware on windows, is there a free version as well for mac? If not, any other free alternatives?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Already asked at [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/456741/how-do-i-install-vmware-player-on-a-mac-os-x) (Credits to the OP). I post the answer here again - slightly modified:

There is no version of VMware Player for OS X. Instead, VMware sells a Mac version of their product called [VMware Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion). You may use it as trial version 30 days for free

If you don't want to purchase VMware Fusion, you can:

- Use Boot Camp to some other OS. The OS itself should run fine.
- Use Boot Camp and run vmplayer from the other OS. (Untested since I do not have a OS/X host)
- Use  [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/). VirtualBox can use virtual hard disks in VMware's VMDK format ([like so](http://techathlon.com/how-to-run-a-vmdk-file-in-oracle-virtualbox/)).

Comment: The answer is outdated. Fusion Player 12 is available now: https://blogs.vmware.com/teamfusion/2020/09/fusion-12-now-available.html

Answer (score 13):

From September 2020 there is free VMWare Fusion Player 12 for macOS ([VMware Fusion Blog: Fusion 12: Now Available!](https://blogs.vmware.com/teamfusion/2020/09/fusion-12-now-available.html)):

> Fusion Player offers a Personal Use License, available for free with a
> valid MyVMware account. Home users, Open Source contributors,
> students, and anyone else can use Fusion Player Free for
> Non-Commercial activity.

You can register and download it from [this VMWare page](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/evalcenter?p=fusion-player-personal)

Comment: this activity seems ceased now... for mac.

Comment: Can you be more specific - what do you mean?

Comment: It works. I just downloaded and installed it and ran an existed VM. Note: I had to create an account on VMWare site to be able to download the Fusion app, and get a personal licence key for free

Answer (score 4):

There is also Parallels Desktop for Mac. Years ago I just received a license as a developer, and until now I did not find in any other hypervisor such an integration

Comment: Parallels is not free

Comment: Just like VMWare fusion isn't.

Comment: I don't understand the down vote.  Giving you a +1 for a good attempt at tackling an old question.  Oh, and  welcome to Ask Different.

Comment: @gbiondo VMWare Workstation for Windows **does** have a free viewer that can run VMs so it is a valid question as to how run a VM for free under MacOS

Comment: @Mark: this topic was for Mac, anyways...

Comment: @gbiondo The question is On Windows there is **free** player for VMWare is there a **free** version ons MacOS

Comment: @Mark the question is poorly worded, but the title makes it clear. Notice that the OP didn't place the verb in a question position for windows, but it did for MacOS. It reads "*given that* there is a free player for vmware on windows, is there a free version as well for mac?

Comment: The question and title is very clear - i there a **free** player for VMWare,  Parallels is not free so does not answer the question

Answer (score 0):

There Is Wine Or Playonmac There Are Free Like Virtualbox

Comment: Yes but not the same. They are not virtual machines